# java.lang.SecurityException: Isolated process not allowed to call startService

Tags: java, android

I am trying to start background service from Application class. here is my code

```
public class App extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    startService(new Intent(this, MessagingService.class));

}
}
```

But I am getting this following Exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.example.introtuce.version10.App: java.lang.SecurityException: Isolated process not allowed to call startService

at Line startService(new Intent(this, MessagingService.class));

Comment: Did you define your service in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yes I define this Service in manifest like this

        <service
            android:name=".Support.Services.MessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:isolatedProcess="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/aintrotuce_logo"

            />

Comment: I think you should remove the `android:isolatedProcess="true"` part.